# Submit form in classic ASP / VB Script

Tags: forms, vbscript, asp-classic, submit, form-submit

There is a classic ASP and when Submit button is clicked, it calls Java Script function. The script contains validation of a text box: frmCode and when this validation is passed or the text box is empty, I want to submit form.

However, Set `frm = window.document.forms(0)` throws an error says `"800a01a8|Object_required:_''"`
I also tried `frm = window.document.forms("form1")` but it did not work either.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
<form Method="post" Action="Test.asp" onSubmit="return OKToSubmit()" id="form1" name="form1" target=_blank>
.....
..... more lines..
.....
<input type="text" id="frmCode" name="frmCode"
style="WIDTH: 248px; HEIGHT: 24px" size=1 maxlength="115">
.....
..... more lines..
.....
<input Type="button" Value="Submit" onClick="OKToSubmit()" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmitn">
.....
..... more lines..
.....
<SCRIPT ID=clientEventHandlersVBS type="text/Javascript">
function OKToSubmit(){
var availableCode = new Array();
<%
    Dim frm 'reference to form
    Set frm = window.document.forms(0)

    idx = 0
    for idx = 0 to UBound(codeList)-1 
%>
    availableCode[<%=idx %>] = unescape('<%= Escape(codeList(idx)) %>');

    <% next %>

    var strCode = document.getElementById('frmCode').value;
    var validationFlag = 0;
    loopValidation:
    for (var i = 0; i < availableCode.length; i++) {
        if (strCode == availableCode[i]){
            validationFlag = 1;
            break loopValidation;
        }
    }
    if (validationFlag == 0 && !(strCode == "")){
        alert("Code does not exist. Please check again.");
        document.getElementById('frmCode').value = "";
        <%
        OKToSubmit = False
        %>
    } else {
        <%
            OKToSubmit = True 
            frm.Submit 
        %>

    }
}

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: why was this question down-voted???

Comment: it's not working because window.document.forms(0) is not valid server side code. Remember, in ASP, anything between the <% %> tags is considered server side code, and is processed BEFORE the page renders to the client. so when the page is processing the server side code, it has no idea what window.document.forms(0) is, thus the reason you're getting the error.

before i can offer a solution, I need to know what is codelist? is it a server side array or something else?

Comment: @Josh Montgomery Thank you for your response. codelist is an array which data is retrieved from database. I also tried window.document.forms[0] in the java script part (outside of <% %>) but it did not work either..

Comment: I think you need to be much clearer about what is running server side and what is running client side. As @Josh Montgomery says, you seem to have muddled the two and got some logic that should be client side within the server-side tags.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

see if this gets you what you want:

```
function OKToSubmit(){
var availableCode = new Array();
var frm = window.document.forms[0];
<%
    idx = 0
    for idx = 0 to UBound(codeList)-1 
%>
    availableCode[<%=idx %>] = unescape('<%= Escape(codeList(idx)) %>');

    <% next %>

    var strCode = document.getElementById('frmCode').value;
    var validationFlag = 0;
    loopValidation:
    for (var i = 0; i < availableCode.length; i++) {
        if (strCode == availableCode[i]){
            validationFlag = 1;
            break loopValidation;
        }
    }
    if (validationFlag == 0 && !(strCode == "")){
        alert("Code does not exist. Please check again.");
        document.getElementById('frmCode').value = "";
        return false;
    } else {
        frm.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for being patient with my basic question.I was confused what cannot be done on each server and client sides but I got a better idea through this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I moved `document.getElementById("form1").submit();` from server side code to client code in Java Script part. Then it is working now. Thank you again for all of your advice.